# Maven with IntelliJ - Failing building process because dependencies can't be resolved

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build, dependencies

First of all, I'm entirely new to Maven. 
I've imported a big complex maven project to IntelliJ. It contains multiple `pom.xml`, and it also depends on another local project (that I've already imported and works well). 
The import process went well; on IntelliJ, nothing is red underlined. It seems to find every dependency (whether local or not). However when I try to build the `.jar` of one of the project via the Maven menu:

[image]

I get this output:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/bastiannanchen/Programmation/Backend/backend/Reconfigure "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=62186:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.3.4 compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Reconfigure 3.3.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for <local_project> is missing, no dependency information available
[...]
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.276 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-12T11:08:44+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 10M/309M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Reconfigure: Could not resolve dependencies for project <project_name> The following artifacts could not be resolved: <local_project> [...]
[...]
```

Do you know how to resolve this problem? I suppose I'm not proceeding correctly with the building process, but I am having a hard time to find an answer on the internet.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The structure of the project in summary:

```
├── backend
│   ├── project_1
│   ├── project_2
│   ├── project_3
│   └── project_4
└── utils
    ├── project_utils_1
    ├── project_utils_2
    └── project_utils_3
```

I'm trying to build, e.g., the `project_2` that has dependencies with all the projects in `backend` and some projects in `utils`.

Comment: can you please provide more data: your project folder structure, and first line of your output of the console

Comment: I don't think a complex, multi-module project should be anyone's first attempt at Maven.  Do you have a choice to try something simpler first?  Post your pom.xml.  Who set up this Maven pom?  How confident are you that they know what they're doing?  Does it work properly for anyone else?   Maybe this can help: https://sookocheff.com/post/java/local-maven-repository/

Comment: @IgorKonoplyanko I've updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @duffymo no I don't have the choice. I need to add some code to this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way to build the `.jar` file. Before building the package, I needed to use the Maven `install` plugin for the dependencies. FYI The Install Plugin is used during the install phase to add artifact(s) to the local repository.

Thank you to everybody that tried to help me :)